# How to embed a modal or popup in an HTML form

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, popup, bootstrap-modal

In my registration form, I'd like users to agree to the T&C without opening a new web page, so a modal (aka dialog or popup) would be appropriate.

But when I add the dialog to the middle of a form, it embeds the form with the close button, and since embedded forms aren't allowed (now the close button tries to submit the form).

I can use Stimulus or Bootstrap, but I'm still not sure how to configure this.  It seems like it must be a common thing.

```html
 <form name="registration_form" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3"><label for="registration_form_email" class="form-label required">Email</label><input type="text" id="registration_form_email" name="registration_form[email]" required="required" maxlength="180" class="form-control" />        </div>
    
        <div class="mb-3"><div class="form-check"><input type="checkbox" id="registration_form_agreeTerms" name="registration_form[agreeTerms]" required="required" aria-describedby="registration_form_agreeTerms_help" class="form-check-input" value="1" />
        <label class="form-check-label required" for="registration_form_agreeTerms">Agree terms</label></div>        <div id="registration_form_agreeTerms_help" class="form-text mb-0 help-text">I agree to the <a href='/terms'>Terms and Conditions</a></div></div>

    <dialog id="modal">
        <h1>Terms and Conditions</h1>
        <p>Use at your own risk!  </p>
        <form method="dialog">
            <button>Close</button>
        </form>
    </dialog>
    <button onclick="modal.show()">Show Terms and Conditions</button>
```